# AngularJS $window.confirm not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('pancakeController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.panCakes = [];

    $scope.removePancake = function(index) {

      if($window.confirm('are you sure?')) {
        $scope.panCakes.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        $scope.panCakes.splice(index, 1);
      }
    };

}]);
```

`myApp` is already defined in another file. I'm using `angular.module('myApp')` to grab a reference to it.

Trying to use `window.confirm()` to confirm the user before deleting a panCake but the confrim box does not popup in Chrome 37.0.2062.94 but does work in Chrome Canary. 
I'm using the AngularJS $window object, but using regular window.confirm does not work either. Is there something that I'm missing in my code or is just a bug in that particular version of Chrome?

Comment: What about omitting $window? Just `confirm("are you sure?")`

Comment: @CollinHenderson the whole point of use $window, and in general any other injected dependency, is that your controller is not bound to any function. With $window injected you can create test that validate your controller logic, without it you can't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most probable cause is that you have at some point checked the little checkbox saying that you don't want to see any more alerts/confirms/prompts from this page.

<sub>(Among other solutions, closing the tab and reopening the page in a new tab should restore alerts/confirms/prompts.)</sub>

Comment: I'll check on that. It works in Chrome Canary so possibly `37.0.2062.9` has this option checked.

Comment: Yes, funny enough this was what it was. I opened a new session in Chrome 37.0.2062.94 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same version of chrome as you are and the above code was not working in the fiddle as you had syntax error in the definition of the angular.module

It should be

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
```

Instead of

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4rtrv7p/)

Comment: I've updated my anwser, the module is defined in another file. I'm using `angular.module('myApp')` to grab a reference to it.